# How can i add my custom layout manager in scene builder?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I've a custom layout manager based on [TitledToolBar](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/apps/samples/Ensemble8/src/app/java/ensemble/control/TitledToolBar.java), anyway it works well outside fxml file but the moment I try to include it on Scene Builder 11 to improve productivity:

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/[user_name]/NetBeansProjects/MyStage/src/main/resources/Test.fxml

    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:101)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:93)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:110)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2560)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:763)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:386)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:665)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenRecent(SceneBuilderApp.java:270)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.menubar.MenuBarController.lambda$updateOpenRecentMenuItems$5(MenuBarController.java:1321)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:465)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1380)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$12(ContextMenuContent.java:1333)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/[user_name]/NetBeansProjects/MyStage/src/main/resources/Test.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2863)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2676)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2542)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2450)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:96)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyStage.CustomLayout
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:718)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2931)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2920)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2861)
    ... 55 more
```

CustomLayout:

```
package MyStage;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class CustomLayout extends TitledToolBar{
    
    public CustomLayout(){
         FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
"/Test.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

Test.fxml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
    <?import MyStage.CustomLayout?>
    
    
    <fx:root type="MyStage.CustomLayout" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
    
    </fx:root>
```

Why can't it find the class location? I don't know what do to anymore... I think i followed all instructions on how to create custom component from [Oracle's website](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm). These days looks like no one cares about JavaFX anymore... Please, help! I'd have followed Ensemble custom title bar sources as example if this:
[image: Ensemble8], was true.

Comment: Same thing here. Even tried class library.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: so far I could see the IOException was caused by Test0.fxml but you gave us the file Test.fxml. Why that? And it seems to me the file is INCOMPLETE. Where is the fx:controller?

Comment: Like I said, I was following Oracle's instructions (javafx 2) about how to create custom control, CustomLayout class like the example shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm#BABIDAHI) is Both the Root and Controller of the FXML Document...

Comment: I believe that the docs should at least be updated, jfx 2 was released on October 10, 2011, many things may have changed... And I don't know for sure if layout manager can be labeled as "custom control". For what I know it's part of scene, but there could still be a way out.